# Golang GAE - Change a variable name in a structure in Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, variables, struct, go, datastore

I am programming a Google Apps Engine Go application and I would like to change a variable name inside a structure that is stored in the datastore.

Say I have a struct:

```
type AA struct{
    A string
    BB string
}
```

And would like to change `BB` into `B`. If I try just changing `BB` into `B`, the datastore will start giving me errors when it would try to assign stored `BB` values to new struct `AA` that does not have that variable. I can add `B` and still keep `BB`, but then the struct would start getting messy.

How can I neatly change variable structure in GAE Go datastore without resorting to temporary copying over the entire database and wiping a lot of data?

Answer (score 3):

You can have your `AA` implement `PropertyLoadSaver` as described in [the Datastore docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Properties), an then

1. in `Load` method copy `BB` into `B`
2. in `Save` method just save `A` and `B`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the App Engine documentation about [Updating Your Model's Schema](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema) tha describes the flow you need to follow in order to update your schema and then delete obsolete properties.

Hope this helps.